# How to get notification of a third party object's property change event?

Tags: c#

I have a third part class object called SomeOnesClass and int property count has only get, I cannot change or extend this class, it doesn't have InotificationChanged implementation, How to get the notification for count value change only with instance of SomeOnesClass.

Comment: Not possible without modifying SomeOnesClass.

Comment: You may want to look in to [Reactive Extensions](https://github.com/Reactive-Extensions/Rx.NET), that will let you set up some code that will watch for changes for you.

Answer (score 1):

Try putting SomeOnesClass into another class, use properties to access SomeOnesClass and raise the event in the setter. E.g.

```
class SomeOnesClassNotification : INotifyPropertyChanged  {
     
     public SomeOnesClassNotification(SomeOnesClass someOnesClass) {
          this.someOnesClass = someOnesClass; 
     }  

     private SomeOnesClass someOnesClass;
     
     private int count;

     public int Count {get {return count; } 
                       set {count = value;  
                            NotifyCountChanged();
                           }
                      }

     void NotifyCountChanged() {
         // Do stuff
     } 

     public event PropertyChangedEventHandler PropertyChanged;

}
```

I'm not too sure of how to implement InotificationChanged, but hopefully this will give you an idea. Note you'd have to use properties or methods to access each of the SomeOnesClass members.

Comment: Set operation is not set by me, There is no set for count in SomeOnesClass

Comment: Yeah, sorry, just read SomeOnesClass only has a getter. Have updated the code to reflect that. Hope this may offer a solution, or maybe suggests another.